# Using Forever; how can I find out the pid of a child process?

Tags: node.js

I'm using [Forever](http://github.com/nodejitsu/forever) in my node.js app. I'm starting a child process like:

```
var forever = require('forever');

child = new (forever.Monitor)('path/to/my/server.js', {
    max: 3,
    silent: true,
    options: []
});

child.start();
```

How can I find out the pid of that child process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var forever = require('forever');

child = new (forever.Monitor)('path/to/my/server.js', {
    max: 3,
    silent: true,
    options: []
});

child.on('start', function(process, data) { console.log(data.pid); });
child.start();
```

Listen to the 'start' event, and it's the pid property of the second argument passed to that callback function.